# Django queryset with for loop and pass to template

Tags: python, django, templates, dictionary

I'm trying to use multi search. For example I will search for "Feas.Meat". And my search result will return me Fish and Meat product.I'm Splitting the search input using split function. And using Django Filter to get search query. But Filter returns query set. I can't figure out how to send a list of a query set for specific text using a loop in a formatted manner like Array List. I want something Like:
[ 'Fish': 'Fish Queryset', 'Meat': 'Meat Querysset']. I'm explicitly sending variable by variable for 2/3 inputs. I want to send in like an array list to the template.
My View Function:

```
#Split Definitions change only  here

search_input = search_text.split('.')
len_search_items = len(search_input)

#Create search query for appropriated searched products

if(len_search_items==1):
        search_split = search_input[0]
        #Store the split search text in Array

        searched_products=list(Item.objects.filter(title__contains=search_split))
        args = { 'len_search_items':len_search_items,'search_split':search_split,'form':form, 'search_input':search_input,'searched_products':searched_products,'search_text':search_text}
```

Template Code:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block search_content %}

<h2>Search Page</h2>

{% include "snippets/search-form.html" %}

<h2> String Separatin={{ search_input }}</h2>
<h2> Searched For={{ search_text }}</h2>

<h2>  Searched For ={{ len_search_items }} products</h2>
<h2>  Search Found Result  ={{ searched_products_len }} products</h2> 
<h2> Searched For ={{ search_split }}</h2>

{% if searched_products %}
<ul>

    <h2>Searched Product List</h2>
    {% for item in searched_products %}


    <li> <a href="{% url 'detail' item.id %}">{{ item.title }}</a></li>

    {% endfor %}
</ul>

{% else %}


<h2>No Search Matched</h2>

{% endif %} 


{% if searched_products1 %}
<ul>
    <h2> Searched For ={{ search_split1 }}</h2>
    <h2>Searched Product List</h2>
    {% for item in searched_products1 %}


    <li> <a href="{% url 'detail' item.id %}">{{ item.title }}</a></li>

    {% endfor %}
</ul>

{% else %}


<h2>No Search Matched</h2>

{% endif %}

{% if searched_products2 %}
<ul>
    <h2> Searched For ={{ search_split2 }}</h2>
    <h2>Searched Product List</h2>
    {% for item in searched_products2 %}


    <li> <a href="{% url 'detail' item.id %}">{{ item.title }}</a></li>

    {% endfor %}
</ul>

{% else %}


<h2>No Search Matched</h2>

{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please add your expected output properly.

Comment: Yes.But how can I do that using loop.As I am searching  for multiple items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
search_products = {search_split: Item.objects.filter(title__contains=search_split)}
```

Instead of this:

```
searched_products=list(Item.objects.filter(title__contains=search_split))
```

Then if someone search for meat you will get something like:

```
{'meat': [{'name': 'meat1'}, {'name': 'meat2'}]}
```

I hope i understood well what you want

> I want something Like: [ 'Fish': 'Fish Queryset', 'Meat': 'Meat Querysset'].